# error installing Oracle forms and reports 11G

Tags: oracle11g, oracleforms

```
]]
[2012-07-04T00:27:15.670+05:30] [as] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.as.provisioning] [tid: 13] [ecid: 0000JXDthrbFg4WFLzvH8A1FwmfA000004,0] Executing a Jaxb workflow ...
[2012-07-04T00:27:15.671+05:30] [as] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.as.provisioning] [tid: 13] [ecid: 0000JXDthrbFg4WFLzvH8A1FwmfA000004,0] Begining Oracle Fusion Middleware Configuration ...
[2012-07-04T00:27:15.671+05:30] [as] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.as.provisioning] [tid: 13] [ecid: 0000JXDthrbFg4WFLzvH8A1FwmfA000004,0] ENTRY ASDomain.connectToAdminServer
[2012-07-04T00:27:15.671+05:30] [as] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.as.provisioning] [tid: 13] [ecid: 0000JXDthrbFg4WFLzvH8A1FwmfA000004,0] ENTRY ASDomain._connectToAdminServer
[2012-07-04T00:27:15.671+05:30] [as] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.as.provisioning] [tid: 13] [ecid: 0000JXDthrbFg4WFLzvH8A1FwmfA000004,0] ENTRY ASDomain._getAdminServer
[2012-07-04T00:27:15.671+05:30] [as] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.as.provisioning] [tid: 13] [ecid: 0000JXDthrbFg4WFLzvH8A1FwmfA000004,0] RETURN: _getAdminServer
[2012-07-04T00:27:15.672+05:30] [as] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.as.provisioning] [tid: 13] [ecid: 0000JXDthrbFg4WFLzvH8A1FwmfA000004,0] reportStartConfigAction: ENTRY........
[2012-07-04T00:27:15.672+05:30] [as] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.as.provisioning] [tid: 13] [ecid: 0000JXDthrbFg4WFLzvH8A1FwmfA000004,0] reportStartConfigAction: eventStatus........oracle.as.provisioning.engine.ConfigEventStatus@fd59e
[2012-07-04T00:27:15.672+05:30] [as] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.as.provisioning] [tid: 13] [ecid: 0000JXDthrbFg4WFLzvH8A1FwmfA000004,0] reportStartConfigAction: 2........
[2012-07-04T00:27:15.672+05:30] [as] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.as.provisioning] [tid: 13] [ecid: 0000JXDthrbFg4WFLzvH8A1FwmfA000004,0] reportStartConfigAction: Set the Extion Id to START........
[2012-07-04T00:27:15.672+05:30] [as] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.as.provisioning] [tid: 13] [ecid: 0000JXDthrbFg4WFLzvH8A1FwmfA000004,0] reportStartConfigAction: Did the assignment...
[2012-07-04T00:27:15.672+05:30] [as] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.as.provisioning] [tid: 13] [ecid: 0000JXDthrbFg4WFLzvH8A1FwmfA000004,0] reportStartConfigAction: EXIT........
[2012-07-04T00:27:16.159+05:30] [as] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.as.provisioning] [tid: 13] [ecid: 0000JXDthrbFg4WFLzvH8A1FwmfA000004,0] RETURN: _connectToAdminServer
[2012-07-04T00:27:16.160+05:30] [as] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.as.provisioning] [tid: 13] [ecid: 0000JXDthrbFg4WFLzvH8A1FwmfA000004,0] RETURN: connectToAdminServer
[2012-07-04T00:27:16.160+05:30] [as] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.as.provisioning] [tid: 13] [ecid: 0000JXDthrbFg4WFLzvH8A1FwmfA000004,0] The action type for asinstance is EXISTS
[2012-07-04T00:27:16.160+05:30] [as] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.as.provisioning] [tid: 13] [ecid: 0000JXDthrbFg4WFLzvH8A1FwmfA000004,0] Instance asinst_1 already exists, continuing with component creation
[2012-07-04T00:27:16.160+05:30] [as] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.as.provisioning] [tid: 13] [ecid: 0000JXDthrbFg4WFLzvH8A1FwmfA000004,0] ENTRY ASInstanceProv.createComponent
[2012-07-04T00:27:16.160+05:30] [as] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.as.provisioning] [tid: 13] [ecid: 0000JXDthrbFg4WFLzvH8A1FwmfA000004,0] ENTRY ASInstanceProv._createComponent
[2012-07-04T00:27:16.161+05:30] [as] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.as.provisioning] [tid: 13] [ecid: 0000JXDthrbFg4WFLzvH8A1FwmfA000004,0] reportStartConfigAction: ENTRY........
[2012-07-04T00:27:16.161+05:30] [as] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.as.provisioning] [tid: 13] [ecid: 0000JXDthrbFg4WFLzvH8A1FwmfA000004,0] reportStartConfigAction: eventStatus........oracle.as.provisioning.engine.ConfigEventStatus@1411393
[2012-07-04T00:27:16.161+05:30] [as] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.as.provisioning] [tid: 13] [ecid: 0000JXDthrbFg4WFLzvH8A1FwmfA000004,0] reportStartConfigAction: 2........
[2012-07-04T00:27:16.161+05:30] [as] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.as.provisioning] [tid: 13] [ecid: 0000JXDthrbFg4WFLzvH8A1FwmfA000004,0] reportStartConfigAction: Set the Extion Id to START........
[2012-07-04T00:27:16.161+05:30] [as] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.as.provisioning] [tid: 13] [ecid: 0000JXDthrbFg4WFLzvH8A1FwmfA000004,0] reportStartConfigAction: Did the assignment...
[2012-07-04T00:27:16.161+05:30] [as] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.as.provisioning] [tid: 13] [ecid: 0000JXDthrbFg4WFLzvH8A1FwmfA000004,0] reportStartConfigAction: EXIT........
[2012-07-04T00:27:16.161+05:30] [as] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.as.provisioning] [tid: 13] [ecid: 0000JXDthrbFg4WFLzvH8A1FwmfA000004,0] Start of create component
[2012-07-04T00:27:16.170+05:30] [as] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.as.provisioning] [tid: 13] [ecid: 0000JXDthrbFg4WFLzvH8A1FwmfA000004,0] Action for the ReportsTools is CREATE
[2012-07-04T00:27:16.170+05:30] [as] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.as.provisioning] [tid: 13] [ecid: 0000JXDthrbFg4WFLzvH8A1FwmfA000004,0] Trying to create the component ReportsTools
[2012-07-04T00:27:16.173+05:30] [as] [TRACE:16] [] [oracle.as.config] [tid: 13] [ecid: 0000JXDthrbFg4WFLzvH8A1FwmfA000004,0] [SRC_CLASS: oracle.as.config.impl.OracleASInstanceProvisioner] [SRC_METHOD: directoryIsPopulated] directoryIsPopulated found unexcluded file/dir: C:\oracle\Middleware\asinst_1\auditlogs
[2012-07-04T00:27:16.174+05:30] [as] [TRACE:32] [] [oracle.as.config] [tid: 13] [ecid: 0000JXDthrbFg4WFLzvH8A1FwmfA000004,0] [SRC_CLASS: oracle.as.config.impl.OracleASInstanceProvisioner] [SRC_METHOD: calcDirectoryStatus] Oracle Instance directory status: INSTANCE
[2012-07-04T00:27:16.275+05:30] [as] [ERROR] [] [oracle.as.provisioning] [tid: 13] [ecid: 0000JXDthrbFg4WFLzvH8A1FwmfA000004,0] [[
oracle.as.config.exception.LocationAlreadyUsedException: A directory for component ReportsTools already exists.  Delete this component first.
    at oracle.as.config.impl.OracleASComponentBaseImpl.validateNotExistOnDisk(OracleASComponentBaseImpl.java:541)
    at oracle.as.config.impl.OracleASComponentBaseImpl.create(OracleASComponentBaseImpl.java:94)
    at oracle.as.provisioning.fmwadmin.ASComponentProv.createComponent(ASComponentProv.java:144)
    at oracle.as.provisioning.fmwadmin.ASComponentProv.createComponent(ASComponentProv.java:73)
    at oracle.as.provisioning.fmwadmin.ASInstanceProv._createComponent(ASInstanceProv.java:401)
    at oracle.as.provisioning.fmwadmin.ASInstanceProv.createComponent(ASInstanceProv.java:358)
    at oracle.as.provisioning.fmwadmin.ASInstanceProv.createInstanceAndComponents(ASInstanceProv.java:136)
    at oracle.as.provisioning.engine.WorkFlowExecutor._createASInstancesAndComponents(WorkFlowExecutor.java:523)
    at oracle.as.provisioning.engine.WorkFlowExecutor.executeWLSWorkFlow(WorkFlowExecutor.java:439)
    at oracle.as.provisioning.engine.Config.executeConfigWorkflow_WLS(Config.java:866)
    at oracle.as.install.classic.ca.standard.StandardWorkFlowExecutor.execute(StandardWorkFlowExecutor.java:65)
    at oracle.as.install.classic.ca.standard.AbstractProvisioningTask.execute(AbstractProvisioningTask.java:26)
    at oracle.as.install.classic.ca.standard.StandardProvisionTaskList.execute(StandardProvisionTaskList.java:61)
    at oracle.as.install.classic.ca.ClassicConfigMain.doExecute(ClassicConfigMain.java:124)
    at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.client.ConfigAction.execute(ConfigAction.java:339)
    at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.action.TaskPerformer.run(TaskPerformer.java:87)
    at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.action.TaskPerformer.startConfigAction(TaskPerformer.java:104)
    at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.action.ActionRequest.perform(ActionRequest.java:15)
    at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.action.RequestQueue.perform(RequestQueue.java:63)
    at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.standard.StandardConfigActionManager.start(StandardConfigActionManager.java:158)
    at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.boot.ConfigurationExtension.kickstart(ConfigurationExtension.java:81)
    at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.ConfigurationModule.run(ConfigurationModule.java:83)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

]]
[2012-07-04T00:27:16.275+05:30] [as] [ERROR] [] [oracle.as.provisioning] [tid: 13] [ecid: 0000JXDthrbFg4WFLzvH8A1FwmfA000004,0] [[
oracle.as.provisioning.engine.CfgWorkflowException
    at oracle.as.provisioning.engine.Engine.processEventResponse(Engine.java:596)
    at oracle.as.provisioning.fmwadmin.ASInstanceProv.createComponent(ASInstanceProv.java:368)
    at oracle.as.provisioning.fmwadmin.ASInstanceProv.createInstanceAndComponents(ASInstanceProv.java:136)
    at oracle.as.provisioning.engine.WorkFlowExecutor._createASInstancesAndComponents(WorkFlowExecutor.java:523)
    at oracle.as.provisioning.engine.WorkFlowExecutor.executeWLSWorkFlow(WorkFlowExecutor.java:439)
    at oracle.as.provisioning.engine.Config.executeConfigWorkflow_WLS(Config.java:866)
    at oracle.as.install.classic.ca.standard.StandardWorkFlowExecutor.execute(StandardWorkFlowExecutor.java:65)
    at oracle.as.install.classic.ca.standard.AbstractProvisioningTask.execute(AbstractProvisioningTask.java:26)
    at oracle.as.install.classic.ca.standard.StandardProvisionTaskList.execute(StandardProvisionTaskList.java:61)
    at oracle.as.install.classic.ca.ClassicConfigMain.doExecute(ClassicConfigMain.java:124)
    at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.client.ConfigAction.execute(ConfigAction.java:339)
    at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.action.TaskPerformer.run(TaskPerformer.java:87)
    at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.action.TaskPerformer.startConfigAction(TaskPerformer.java:104)
    at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.action.ActionRequest.perform(ActionRequest.java:15)
    at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.action.RequestQueue.perform(RequestQueue.java:63)
    at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.standard.StandardConfigActionManager.start(StandardConfigActionManager.java:158)
    at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.boot.ConfigurationExtension.kickstart(ConfigurationExtension.java:81)
    at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.ConfigurationModule.run(ConfigurationModule.java:83)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: oracle.as.provisioning.util.ConfigException: 
Error creating ASComponent ReportsTools.
Cause: 
An internal operation has failed: A directory for component ReportsTools already exists.  Delete this component first.
Action: 
See logs for more details.
    at oracle.as.provisioning.util.ConfigException.createConfigException(ConfigException.java:123)
    at oracle.as.provisioning.fmwadmin.ASInstanceProv._createComponent(ASInstanceProv.java:414)
    at oracle.as.provisioning.fmwadmin.ASInstanceProv.createComponent(ASInstanceProv.java:358)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: oracle.as.config.exception.LocationAlreadyUsedException: A directory for component ReportsTools already exists.  Delete this component first.
    at oracle.as.config.impl.OracleASComponentBaseImpl.validateNotExistOnDisk(OracleASComponentBaseImpl.java:541)
    at oracle.as.config.impl.OracleASComponentBaseImpl.create(OracleASComponentBaseImpl.java:94)
    at oracle.as.provisioning.fmwadmin.ASComponentProv.createComponent(ASComponentProv.java:144)
    at oracle.as.provisioning.fmwadmin.ASComponentProv.createComponent(ASComponentProv.java:73)
    at oracle.as.provisioning.fmwadmin.ASInstanceProv._createComponent(ASInstanceProv.java:401)
    ... 18 more

]]
```

I have installed the forms and reports 11g successfully.Then I am configuring forms.
Can any one help me solve this error occurred during configuration of Oracle forms and Reports 11G?Which directory it is talking about and were is it located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have had some failed configuration attempts prior to this one. I would uninstall and start-over. Make sure that you remove any "Oracle Process Manager" services are running in your windows services before you install.

I've also seen this when your IP Address isnt mapped to your fully qualified domain and/or machine name in your host file.

What exact version numbers of WLS and Forms are you installing?